# Handling Nested Objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am struggling a bit to wrap my head around Entity Framework and It's driving me crazy. I have an target object that I'd like to populate:

```
public class ApiInvitationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EventModel Event { get; set; }
    public UserModel InvitationSentTo { get; set; }
    public UserModel AttendingUser { get; set; }
}
```

The schemas of the above models are:

```
public class EventModel {
    public int Id? { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set }
    public OrganizationModel HostingOrganization { get; set; }
    public Venue Venue { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel {
    public int Id? { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public List<OrganizationModel> Organizations { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationModel {
    public int Id? { get; set; }
    public stirng Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public UserModel PrimaryContact { get; set; }
}
```

The above schemas are simplified for the purpose of the question and are the models we intend to return via API.

The problem is the origin schemas in the database is very different and I'm trying to map the database objects to these objects via Entity Framework 6.

My attempted solution was to try and nest the models via a query but that didn't work and I'm not sure where to go from here besides making numerous calls to the database.

```
public List<ApiInvitationModel> GetInvitations(int userId) {
    
    using (var entities = new Entities()) {
        return entities.EventInvitations
            .Join(entities.Users, invitation => invitiation.userId, user => user.id, (invitation, user) => new {invitation, user})
            .Join(entities.Events, model => model.invitation.eventId, ev => ev.id, (model, ev) => new {model.invitation, model.user, ev})
            .Join(entities.organization, model => model.user.organizationId, organization => organization.id, (model, organization) => new ApiInvitationModel 
            {
                Id = model.invitation.id,
                Event = new EventModel {
                    Id = model.event.id,
                    Name = model.event.name,
                    StartDate = model.event.startDate,
                    EndDate = model.event.endDate,
                    HostingOrganization = new OrganizationModel {
                        Id = model.invitation.hostingId,
                        Name = model.event.venueName,
                        Address = model.event.address,
                        PrimaryContact = new UserModel {
                            Name = model.event.contactName,
                            PhoneNumber = model.event.contactNumber,
                        }
                    }
                    ...
                },
                InvitedUser = {
                
                }
            }
            ).ToList();
    }

}
```

As you can see above, there's quite a bit of nesting going on but this doesn't work in Entity Framework 6 as far as I am aware. I keep getting the following errors:

```
"The type 'Entities.Models.API.UserModel' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.",
```

Based on the above error, I assumed that each of the model initiatilizations would need to be the same (i.e. initializing the values as the same `ApiInvitationModel` in each join in the same order) but that produces the same error.

What would be the best approach to handling this, keepign in mind the source database doesn't have foreign keys implemented?

Comment: are you using CodeFirst or DatabaseFirst Approach ?

Comment: @Ben.S Database first

Comment: and I understand that the above class are not the models ? because if they are 
they should be reflecting the DB schemas

Comment: You would be correct in assuming the above classes are not the database models

Comment: so you can retrieve the data you need via the entity models and than populate
those classes

Comment: maybe try to initialize the classes outside of the LINQ, after you retrieve the data you need by LINQ, because the error seems to be relevant only to the  LINQ part

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. Cheers.

Comment: `'Entities.Models.API.UserModel' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ` this is the problem, try extracting the initializations ,most important the UserModel, outside of LINQ